# User fields that can be edited by administrator?

Tags: php, wordpress, customization, field

How can I add custom user fields for a user profile that an administrator can edit? I want the user to be able to see the value of the field on their profile, but I don't want them to edit it. How can I achieve this with WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this plugin? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/extra-user-fields/ Maybe it can help you.